# Older uninstaller in control panel uninstall list disappears when a new version is installed alongside

Tags: inno-setup

I've got an application which I have installed alongside a newer version  with a different `AppVersion`, but identical `AppId`. If I check the control panel, I noticed installing two versions alsongside  **erases** the older uninstaller entry in the Control Panel uninstall list.  Why does InnoSetup do this? This forces the user to  have to manually determine the uninstaller for the other application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's as designed. The [`AppId`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid) identifies the software. You are not supposed to install another copy of an application with the same `AppId` to a different folder. If you use the same folder, the uninstaller of the latest installation would take care of all installed versions.

See https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=sameappnotes

If you want to allow parallel installations of different versions, you have to have the `AppId` unique per version.

Note that the entry in the uninstall list is not *erased*, it is *overwritten*, as the `AppId` is the key for the list.